# Why is there a huge difference between bandwidth and download speed?

Tags: download, speed, bandwidth

I'm using a broadband connection of bandwidth 1Mbps(the online speed check confirms this). But the download speed doesn't exceed 110kbps.

Now, when I'm talking of kbps, I'm talking of kbps (kilo-bits per second which is = 128 bytes), and not KBps (kiLo-bytes per second which is = 1024 bytes).

Even if the bandwidth and the download speed are in kbps, there is still a huge difference.

It's normal to lose about 25% of the bandwidth speed, but I'm not even getting 20%. Could my service provider have limited the maximum speed? Let's say it's the provider's policy to have the limit. Is there a way to get the appropriate speed myself?

Comment: 1) Does this happens with all sites? Or do you get full speed when downloading from another (faster) site?   2) If the provider limits downloads per connection when you should be able to download multiple files at the same times without slowing the first download down. Please test this and add the results.

Comment: •transmission protocol •protocol overhead •poor signal •bandwidth-sharing •throttling     There’s plenty of potential causes but you have not provided enough information to determine which one(s).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're downloading. Some protocols are faster than others.  For instance, downloading via HTTP (from a web site) is usually a lot slower than via FTP.  Speed tests use methods that show what is technically possible, but in practical terms usually not attainable.